# angularjs view not getting updated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, view, angular-ui-router

Here is a small self-contained html todo application using routes...

It has two views - list.html and add.html

### list.html:

```
<div>    
    <a href="#/add" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="setNewTask()">Add Task</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="container" id="tasks">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                <button ng-show="!task.done" ng-click="markTaskAsDone(task)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span></button>
                <button ng-show="task.done" ng-click="markTaskAsNotDone(task)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span></button>
                <button ng-click="removeTask(task)" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></button>
                &nbsp;
                <s ng-show="task.done">{{task.desc}}</s>
                <span ng-show="!task.done">{{task.desc}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p ng-show="tasks.length == 0">Add few tasks</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### add.html:

```
<div>
    <a href="#/" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>&nbsp;Back</a>
    <h2>Add a task</h2>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="newTask.desc" placeholder="Enter Task..." class="form-control" />
        <a href="#/list" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="addNewTask()">Add</a>        
    </div>
</div>
```

I only have one controller.

```
controllers = {
    ToDoController: function ($scope, $timeout, $location) {

        //two items in by default...
        $scope.tasks = [
            { desc: 'Buy milk', done: false },
            { desc: 'Collect newspaper', done: false }
        ];

        $scope.newTask = { desc: '', done: false };

        $scope.addNewTask = function () {
            $location.path('/');
            console.log('a');
            $scope.tasks.push($scope.newTask);            
        }

        $scope.markTaskAsDone = function (task) {            
            task.done = true;
            console.log($scope.tasks);
        }

        $scope.markTaskAsNotDone = function (task) {
            task.done = false;
        };

        $scope.removeTask = function (task) {
            $scope.tasks.splice($scope.tasks.indexOf(task), 1);
        };

        //called to set newTask
        $scope.setNewTask = function () {
            $scope.newTask = { desc: '', done: false };            
        };
    }
};
```

My shell page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ToDo List</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        #tasks ul {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            list-style: none;
            font-size: large;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TODO App</h1>
    <div data-ng-app="todoApp">
        <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/todo.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('todoApp', ['ngRoute']);
        app.controller(controllers);
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/list', {
                    controller: 'ToDoController',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'
                })
            .when('/add', {
                controller: 'ToDoController',
                templateUrl: 'partials/add.html'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/list' });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Issue:

When I load index.html its shows the list.html. The two default items I've put shows up. I click on Add and navigate to the second view (add.html), enter details and click on the Add button in that page...I navigate to the list.html view, but its still showing the old list...not the updated list...

Surely missing some api call to do the update to the view...else this page is coming from some cache. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToDoController is instantiated twice and separately for your two views. To maintain 1 instance of the controller to control both views, don't declare it in your routing, but declare it on a parent tag of the views.

For instance, like this:

```
<div data-ng-app="todoApp" data-ng-controller="ToDoController">
    <div data-ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Even better is to write separate controllers for each view to put the view-specific logic into, and have 1 parent controller to store values that both controllers should have access to.

Another way to share scope among isolated controllers is using $rootScope, but you should normally try to avoid using that (like you would try to avoid using global variables in any programming language).

Comment: So when defining routes whats the right way to handle this?

Comment: I would write separate controllers for each view. Then if you want these controllers to share certain values in the scope, you can either write a third 'parent' controller, or use $rootScope.